# How to execute query with UNION in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm performing a SQL query through hibernate, which looks like:

```
@Query("(select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' AND " +
        "category.id in (select cat.id from Category cat where cat.isDelete=false and cat.status='A' and cat.parentCategory IS NOT NULL))" +
        "UNION" +
        "(select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' and category.parentCategory IS NOT NULL)")
```

But it showing me error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

Comment: Hay Janes,
its hibernate framework in java, category refers to all columns of table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your query is fine at sql level, but in case of Hibernate you will face this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

so convert this query

```
@Query("(select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' AND " +
    "category.id in (select cat.id from Category cat where cat.isDelete=false and cat.status='A' and cat.parentCategory IS NOT NULL))" +
    "UNION" +
    "(select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' and category.parentCategory IS NOT NULL)")
```

into two queries

```
@Query("select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' AND " +
    "category.id in (select cat.id from Category cat where cat.isDelete=false and cat.status='A' and cat.parentCategory IS NOT NULL)")

@Query("select category from Category category where category.isDelete=false and category.status='A' and category.parentCategory IS NOT NULL")
```

and call them by different methods.

Answer (score 1):

**How do you select category is their any field like that and you have mentioned you category table as category** fix it then try either other approach is alright *you can check it also by giving asterisk as * and your rest of the query is correct*